# Looking for feedback to design a tabbed menu

Tags: website-design, interface-design, user-experience

I am working on an e-commerce website. I am creating a Shopify app for the e-commerce website, and I want the shopify app to be within a tabbed menu.

The app has 2 tabs:

1. `Product Mapping`: for defining product mapping between Shopify and my e-commerce
2. `Online Store`: for defining organisation setting such as Name, address
3. I might add extra tabs for `Payment method` and `Help`

I created 3 similar variations of this tabbed menu and am trying to find out which design is the best...

*Note: if user clicks on any of these tabs, a full post back will occur and the entire page is refreshed.*

**Design 1 (Tabbed menu with no border)**

[image]

**Design 2 (Tabbed menu with no border, but table is inside a card)**

[image]

**Design 3 (Tabbed menu with border)**

[image]

I am looking for feedback to decide which one of these designs to use...

In case of tabbed menu, is it more common to have a border around the tabbed 
menu?

Comment: I don't know if it is just me but I see no difference between 3 designs, have you uploaded the correct images?

Comment: The difference is in the border of tabbed menu.

Answer (score 0):

Third one is ok, but overall the design is rather poor and could use some improvement. If you haven't done this before, try to get some [inspiration](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=interface%20design%20admin&va=z&t=hk&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images).